# Have $2s_{1/2}$ and $2p_{1/2}$ the same energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I have always known that p-states are more energetic than s-states. But in this picture I see the following: [image]

And it confused me. Could anyone explain if both levels have the same energy?

Comment: Where did the diagram come from? What system is it referring to?

Comment: @JohnRennie from lecture notes.. it is referring to the hydrogen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energies of the states of the hydrogen atom do not depend on the orbital angular momentum $\ell$ ($s$, $p$, $d$, ...) but on the combined angular momentum $j$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Energy_levels)), which also takes into account the spin of the electron, i.e. $j=\ell\pm\frac{1}{2}$ for hydrogen. Therefore, the $s$-orbital state with electron spin $1/2$ has the same combined angular momentum as the $p$ orbital state with electron spin $-1/2$ and, consequently, the two have the same energy. This is only true when not considering the Lamb shift and hyperfine structure. The [Lamb shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift) splits the $2p_{1/2}$ and the $2s_{1/2}$, but the effect is an order of magnitude smaller than the fine structure splitting between $2p_{1/2}$ and $2p_{3/2}$.